# Odoo 9 Windows all in one not detecting Shapely

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, windows-server-2012, shapely

I installed Odoo 9 All in One on a Windows 2012 Server. Installed python 2.7, postgis, geojson, and shapely.

When I try to install the geoengine camp2camp module I get an error Unable to install base_geoengine because external dependency is not met. No module named shapely

[image: Error]

Can anyone please give me some guidance?

I was able to get this module installed in Ubuntu but would really like it on a Windows server for some testing.

Comment: You should install those libraries using the pip installer in your Odoo install directory when you're using windows.

Answer (score 0):

You simply don't have shapely installed open the command prompt and do

`pip install shapely`

if that doesn't work for you visit this link

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#shapely

and download shapely based on your **PYTHON VERSION (32 or 64 bit)** not your OS type

after installing restart odoo

Comment: That is the problem I am having. I did install Shapely already
pip install ==shapely1.5.9
When I try to install the base_geoengine module for openerp I get the error about external dependencies 
I used the whl package form this site http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#shapely

Its like the module doesnt detect that it is installed. I am running Windows Server 2012 with Openerp all in one install V9

Comment: run pip freeze and check if it's listed

Comment: if its not listed then it's not installed....make sure you download the one according to your version of python

Comment: pip freeze 
geojson==1.3.2
Shapely==1.5.15

I must be missing something! I have very little experience in python I just want to get this installed module working!

Comment: do you have multiple python2 versions or do you use a virtualenv?

Answer (score 0):

If you have shapely installed using `pim install shapely`, simply go to the packages folder: eg C:\pythonXX\Lib\site-packages, the copy the 'Shapely' folder and paste it in the Odoo 10.0\server folder. Restart your Odoo server and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I encountered the same problem. I am using Odoo 10 with Pycharm.
The problem was that Shapely was installed in my python 2.7 but not in my interpreters library.

Kindly check your interpreters libraries

For more info kindly  refer to this link 
[How to install packages to set interpreter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html)